# how can i return fetch() in map() loop

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, dictionary

I wrote a webapp about weather and i used weatherbit api that is just free part. i want to fetch() funk in map() loop .
i have an object which has cityname and country name . map() return every cityname and country with fetch()
 how can i do that? 
one more question every step of map() loop i get one JSON .. Maybe and of the loop i have 10 JSON... How can i match all Json into one Json?
here is the code..

```js
 const cityName = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ingolstadt",
    "country": "GE",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Vienna",
    "country": "AT",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Istanbul",
    "country": "TR",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "London",
    "country": "GB",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Ankara",
    "country": "TR",
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Paris",
    "country": "FR",
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Barcelona",
    "country": "ES",
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Amsterdam",
    "country": "NL",
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Belgrade",
    "country": "RS",
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Munich",
    "country": "GE",
  }
]

//should return all city which are in object
 
const citySource = cityName.map((name , country) => {
// get api from weatherbit api , but i dont know ${name} and ${country} right sycntax
    fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=${name}&country=${country}&key=86e622607fbe4c2cb9f7f71889a4d48d`)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then( users => console.log(users));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Here you have working example:

```js
const cityName = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ingolstadt",
    "country": "GE",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Vienna",
    "country": "AT",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Istanbul",
    "country": "TR",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "London",
    "country": "GB",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Ankara",
    "country": "TR",
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Paris",
    "country": "FR",
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Barcelona",
    "country": "ES",
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Amsterdam",
    "country": "NL",
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Belgrade",
    "country": "RS",
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Munich",
    "country": "GE",
  }
]

//should return all city which are in object
 
const citySource = cityName.map((city) => {
    fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=${city.name}&country=${city.country}&key=86e622607fbe4c2cb9f7f71889a4d48d`)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then( users => console.log(users));
})
```

Comment: thank you.i want to ask one more question.run perfect. i createad basic weather app with react, and i want to all json file push the STATE but i can not do that. 
i write this top 
``` import {cityName} from './Resorces';``` 
and 
```componentDidMount(){
  const citySource = cityName.map((city) => {
    return fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=${city.name}&country=${city.country}&key=86e622607fbe4c2cb9f7f71889a4d48d`)
      }).then(response => response.json())
// cities is my object name in the STATE
       .then( data => {this.setState({cities : data})});```

Comment: how can i do that